# How to remove border from Textbox in WPF?

Tags: wpf, xaml, textbox

[image]

These borders appear when they are clicked or hovered and don't go until the focus is lost.
There are borders on all four sides but since it is embedded in a shorter grid, the top and bottom ones are not visible.
How to remove these borders? 
Please provide an example if possible.

**XAML:**

```
<Border x:Name="SearchBorder" BorderThickness="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="40" Margin="672,34,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="355" Background="#3F000000">
        <Border.BorderBrush>
            <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                <GradientStop Color="#4C000000" Offset="0"/>
                <GradientStop Color="#3FFFFFFF" Offset="1"/>
            </LinearGradientBrush>
        </Border.BorderBrush>
        <Grid>
            <TextBox x:Name="SearchBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="40" Width="296" Margin="10,0,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Center"  SelectionBrush="Black" Background="#00000000" Foreground="#FF5B5B5B" FontSize="25" FontFamily="Segoe UI Light" BorderBrush="#00000000" CaretBrush="#FF6C6C6C"/>
            <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="320,0,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="&#xF002;" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="21" FontFamily="FontAwesome" FontSize="25" Foreground="#FF919191"/>
            <Rectangle HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="311,-2,0,0" Width="1">
                <Rectangle.Stroke>
                    <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                        <GradientStop Color="#3F404040" Offset="0"/>
                        <GradientStop Color="#3F686868" Offset="1"/>
                        <GradientStop Color="#59DADADA" Offset="0.502"/>
                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                </Rectangle.Stroke>
            </Rectangle>
        </Grid>
    </Border>
```

Comment: That doesn't look like Combo's default style, so it'd help if you shared your XAML Styles and Templates.

Comment: xaml code posted. there are no additional styles

Comment: Have you tried `BorderThickness="0"`?

Answer (score 73, accepted):

Try `BorderThickness="0"`

```
<TextBox x:Name="SearchBox" BorderThickness="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="40" Width="296" Margin="10,0,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Center"  SelectionBrush="Black" Background="#00000000" Foreground="#FF5B5B5B" FontSize="25" FontFamily="Segoe UI Light" BorderBrush="#00000000" CaretBrush="#FF6C6C6C"/>
```

Answer (score 5):

you can remove the border by just setting the BorderBrush property to Transparent.

Comment: Pretty sure that won't work. Check my code it does have BorderBrush set to #00000000 in the XAML

Answer (score 1):

> **Normal View:** Set the BorderBrush property to "Transparent"

```
<Button Name="BtnTest"
        Content="Test"
        BorderBrush="Transparent"
        Height="20"
        Width="75"/>
```

> **Hovering View:** While you are hovering the control with mouse, Include these Control Template for Button or any control like Textbox or Textblock etc.. under the Window.Resources Tag

```
<Window.Resources>
           <Style TargetType="Button">

                <!--Default Values-->
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush"
                        Value="Transparent"/>

                <!--Transparent Highlight-->
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                            <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                                <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                                                  VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                            </Border>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>

            </Style>
</Window.Resources>
```

Comment: Setting the borderbrush property to Transparent did exactly what I needed.